# can different magento API's called from 1 application?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, api, magento

**Magento** - Is that possible to have 1 client application and from it calling sevral magento website API's?

e.g 
magentoClient.com(asp.net MVC application) will call/integrate with API from magentoshoppingcart1.com, magentoshoppingcart2.com, magentoshoppingcart3.com and goes on ..
Please correct me if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes. Why not? I have implemented similar site.